# About functions from an index set to the set being indexed.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $\{I_α\}_{α∈A}$ be a family of open intervals of $\mathbb{R}$, where $A$ is an index set (in other words, each $I_α$ looks like $(a,b)$ for some $a < b$). Suppose that these open intervals are pairwise disjoint. Show that the index set $A$ is countable.

My question here is, the function $f:A \to I$, where I =$\{I_α\}$, is it injective? I am given a hint to construct an injection from $A$ to $\mathbb{Q}$, but I assume $A$ has to go through $I$ first. Do I assume $f$ is injective? I thought that $f$  is only assumed to be a surjection.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ is not assumed to be injective.  Note, though, that when the problem says the open intervals are pairwise disjoint, that means that if $\alpha,\beta\in A$ are distinct, then $I_\alpha\cap I_\beta=\emptyset$.  Since $I_\alpha$ and $I_\beta$ are nonempty, this inplies that actually $I_\alpha\neq I_\beta$, so that $f$ is injective.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you.